# Core-Plot with Xamarin MonoTouch / Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin.ios, core-plot, xamarin-studio

I am using the current Xamarin Studio and trying to get a Core Plot Project up and running.
Importing via the component gallery works perfect.

Now I have scatter graph up and running with zooming and panning working.

I like to have the X and Y axis fixed - always visible - regardless of the displayed range of data.

Setting the IsFloating property on an XPTXYAxis leads to a Crash.

It seems that this is obsolete anyway?

Unfortunately the axisConstraints Parameter is not there - as this seems to be the way to fix the axis on the left or right side of the view.

Any idea how to fix that? Maybe the binding has a problem there?

Comment: What version of Core Plot are you using?

Comment: I tested the github Version 0.9 too. Included the axisConstraints (it was commented out stangely). But Setting it to 
y.Constraints = new CPTConstraints{Lower=CPTConstraint.Fixed, Upper= CPTConstraint.None}; is crashing the app.

Comment: Can you update to a newer version of Core Plot? The official repository lives on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/). The current release is 1.1 and there have been some bug fixes and other changes since then.

Comment: The Problem with updating is, that I am not the author of the MonoTouch binding project.
I suspect that the MonoTouch binding of the Constraints is not complete - as I am not able to assign an CPTConstrainedPosition to the axisConstraint property.
I tried the 1.1 version just via replacing it and keep the old binding definitions but it seems not to work either.
Maybe we need some MonoTouch binding expert now :)